# C# Generics - Constraining types to those that implement a property or field

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic class to handle incoming service requests and I was wondering if its possible to restrict the generic type allowed by the implementation of a property?

From previous experience I have not come across a method to do this but was wondering if anyone else has.

```
internal class RequestProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TResponse : INotifyPropertyChanged, new()
{
}


internal class RequestProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TResponse : <?implements some property or field?>, new()
{
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate. I think the answer to the OP is that the class should have a Where on IMyInterface where IMyInterface is a contract that implements the required property.

Comment: That would work if I could change the generic types that were to be passed in but in this case I can't.